# Trouble on using the i18n gem with the mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, internationalization

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I would like to know how to correctly handle internationalization related to the mailer. That is, ...

... in my `app/views/users/mailer/_custom.html.erb` file I have:

```
...
<%= @test_email.to_s %>
...
```

... in my `app/mailers/users/mailer.rb` file I have:

```
class Users::Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def custom(user)
    ...
    @test_email = t('test_email')
    # I also tried to use '@test_email = I18n.t('test_email')'
  end
end
```

By using the above code the `@test_email.to_s` text is not displayed (it seems to be blank) in the sent email and the [I18n gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n) seems don't accomplish correctly what should be done. **How can I solve the problem so to properly display the locale message in the "aimed" email body?**

---

**UPDATE** for *@volodymyr*

The code you posted in your answer doesn't work for me. I tried also to add the following code to my `config/locales/defaults/en.yml` file:

```
en:
  hello: Test text!!!
```

The `Test text!!!` is still not displayed in the sent email (it is blank).

Comment: Try to enclose it with quotes. Eg 
en:
   hello: "Test text"

Comment: @volodymyr - The problem wasn't related to quotes... read the comment below your answer for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of working code(I`m using Rails 3.1.0 and ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570)):

```
# Fragment of mailer
def test_locale
    @test_email = I18n.t('hello')
    mail(:to => "<your_email_goes_here>", :subject => "test")
end

# Contents of test_locale.html.erb
String, retrieved from I18n: <%= @test_email %>
```

For testing I used Rails console:

```
MyMailer.test_locale.deliver
```

So you need to check if:

- Erb template file name matches mailer`s method name
- There is corresponding record in localization file
- Variable names in mailer method and template file match
- Folder name in "views" matches mailer name

UPDATE: Try to enclose string with quotes in localization file:

```
en:
    hello: "Some text here"
```

Comment: Maybe I found the solution. I am using the Delayed Job gem and after I restarted jobs (`rake jobs:work` in development mode) it started to work. Thanks.